# httpd error log on centos child pid * exit signal Floating point exception (8)

Tags: linux, apache, centos6

**in httpd error log**

```
[Mon Apr 11 21:36:15 2016] [notice] child pid 8781 exit signal Floating point exception (8)

[Mon Apr 11 21:36:15 2016] [notice] child pid 8783 exit signal Floating point exception (8)

[Mon Apr 11 21:36:15 2016] [notice] child pid 8784 exit signal Floating point exception (8)

[Mon Apr 11 21:36:15 2016] [notice] child pid 8787 exit signal Floating point exception (8)

[Mon Apr 11 21:36:15 2016] [notice] child pid 8788 exit signal Floating point exception (8)

[Mon Apr 11 21:36:15 2016] [notice] child pid 8789 exit signal Floating point exception (8)

[Mon Apr 11 21:36:15 2016] [notice] child pid 8793 exit signal Floating point exception (8)

[Mon Apr 11 21:36:15 2016] [notice] child pid 8794 exit signal Floating point exception (8)
```

all of my websites under white page , but i can open my images in direct link , whats is my server problem ?

additional information 
[root@server ~]#  php -v

```
 PHP 5.5.32 (cli) (built: Mar  1 2016 23:09:06)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.17, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
```

yum list installed | grep "php"

```
 php-cli.x86_64                      5.3.3-46.el6_7.1                   @updates
php-common.x86_64                   5.3.3-46.el6_7.1                   @updates
php-intl.x86_64                     5.3.3-46.el6_7.1                   @updates
php-mcrypt.x86_64                   5.3.3-4.el6                        @epel
php-pear.noarch                     1:1.9.4-4.el6                      @base
```

Comment: I have the same problem on debian